# How to improve the speed of the code below?

Tags: php, performance

i am trying to compare the title of some pages with their URL using the code blow. If i have only one link is ok .. but if i try to search for many links the speed it verry low.. i have to wait verry much. Any idea how to improve it ?

```
                $link = LINK;
                $page_content = file_get_contents($link);

                    if(preg_match('/<title>/',
                        $page_content, $matches)) {

                        if ( ! isset($matches[1])) {
                            echo "Page found" ;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Page not found.";
                    }
```

Comment: With `file_get_contents()` you do a webrequest. So you depend on the speed how long it takes fetching the content. You could cache it for some time, but it wouldn't then always be the live result.

Comment: Perhaps because you've attempted to create an example _but_ there is no comparison here. The code doesn't match the question/problem?

Comment: @Steven how not ? If you make a database with some links and you run that code, you will see the code will get alot of time to run. I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: Your code will not be more efficient than what you have suggested already. The speed is very much dependent on the size of each url page (since you have to download the entire url contents) and the speed of the connection between your server and the url page.

Comment: I mean that your code simply checks for the presence of a `<title>` tag. It doesn't compare it at all?

Comment: You could try to call `file_get_contents($link, false, null, 0, 1000);`. It tells the function to only fetch the first 1000 bytes of the file. But I am not sure that it will speed up the url fetching because I believe that it will download all contents anyway and only return the first 1000 bytes.... But it could be worth a try?

Comment: If you're only trying to check if a url is reachable/exists you could send a HEAD request. This will only return the headers instead of the complete source/page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short explanation

`file_get_contents` is slow, scraping multiple URLs with it is insane, you have to synchronously wait for single request to complete before issuing another request.

---

### Solution

Use multi curl to open multiple connections at once and gather the responses asynchronously with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`.

---

### Benchmark

Let us try to benchmark them by scraping 12 GitHub links. This benchmark shows that multi curl can be approximately 12.19 times faster than `file_get_contents` to scrape 12 GitHub URLs. I believe the diff will dramatically increase as the number of links grows.

---

### file_get_contents benchmark

#### File: single.php

```php
<?php

$links = [
    "https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/php-integral-obfuscator",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/fresh-tea-asm",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/memcpy_benchmark",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/GoogleTranslate",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/latex.teainside.org",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/linux",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/uemacs",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk",
    "https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/Makefile",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/LICENSE",
];

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $page_content = file_get_contents($link);
    if (preg_match("/<title>/S", $page_content, $m)) {
        echo "Link {$link} has a title\n";
    } else {
        echo "Link {$link} does not have a title\n";
    }
}
```

#### Execute

```
root@esteh:/tmp# time php single.php
Link https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2 has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/php-integral-obfuscator has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/fresh-tea-asm has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/memcpy_benchmark has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/GoogleTranslate has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/latex.teainside.org has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/linux has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/uemacs has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk has a title
Link https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc has a title
Link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/Makefile does not have a title
Link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/LICENSE does not have a title

real    0m14.721s
user    0m0.070s
sys 0m0.025s
root@esteh:/tmp#
```

#### It takes 14.721s to scrape 12 links

---

### Multi curl benchmark

#### File: multiple.php

```php
<?php 

$links = [
    "https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/php-integral-obfuscator",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/fresh-tea-asm",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/memcpy_benchmark",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/GoogleTranslate",
    "https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/latex.teainside.org",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/linux",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/uemacs",
    "https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk",
    "https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/Makefile",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/LICENSE",
];

function visit_multiple(array $links, array &$retval): void
{
    $chs = [];
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    foreach ($links as $k => $link) {
        $ch = curl_init($link);
        $chs[] = $ch;
        $retval[$k] = "";
        $writeCallback = function ($ch, string $str) use ($k, &$retval) {
            $retval[$k] .= $str;
            return strlen($str);
        };

        curl_setopt_array($ch,
            [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
                CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => $writeCallback
            ]
        );
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    }

    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        if ($active) {
            curl_multi_select($mh);
        }
    } while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);

    foreach ($chs as $ch) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
}

$retval = [];
visit_multiple($links, $retval);

foreach ($retval as $k => $page_content) {
    if (preg_match("/<title>/S", $page_content, $m)) {
        echo "Link {$links[$k]} has a title\n";
    } else {
        echo "Link {$links[$k]} does not have a title\n";
    }
}
```

#### Execute

```
root@esteh:/tmp# time php multiple.php
Link https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2 has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/php-integral-obfuscator has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/fresh-tea-asm has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/memcpy_benchmark has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/GoogleTranslate has a title
Link https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/latex.teainside.org has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/linux has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/uemacs has a title
Link https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk has a title
Link https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc has a title
Link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/Makefile does not have a title
Link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/0.0.1-rc1/LICENSE does not have a title

real    0m1.207s
user    0m0.165s
sys 0m0.042s
root@esteh:/tmp#
```

#### It only takes 1.207s to scrape 12 links

---

## Bonus

To fulfill the OP request in the comment, I added a title check. If there is a title but the title contains "Page not found", then we assume the page doesn't have a title.

It is a trivial task, but okay.

### Code

```php
<?php 

$links = [
    "https://amzn.to/3x4dxLF", // found
    "https://amzn.to/3qQcrQf", // not found
    "https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2", // found
    "https://github.com/not_found_page", // not found
];

function visit_multiple(array $links, array &$retval): void
{
    $chs = [];
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    $cwd = getcwd();
    foreach ($links as $k => $link) {
        $ch = curl_init($link);
        $chs[] = $ch;
        $retval[$k] = "";
        $writeCallback = function ($ch, string $str) use ($k, &$retval) {
            $retval[$k] .= $str;
            return strlen($str);
        };

        curl_setopt_array($ch,
            [
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
                CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => $writeCallback,
                CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cwd."/my_cookie{$k}.txt",
                CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cwd."/my_cookie{$k}.txt",
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
                    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
                ],
            ]
        );
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    }

    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        if ($active) {
            curl_multi_select($mh);
        }
    } while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);

    foreach ($chs as $k => $ch) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
        @unlink($cwd."/my_cookie{$k}.txt");
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
}

$retval = [];
visit_multiple($links, $retval);

foreach ($retval as $k => $page_content) {
    if (preg_match("/<title(?:\s.*?)?>(.+?)<\/title>/isS", $page_content, $m)) {
        if (!preg_match("/Page not found/i", $m[1])) {
            echo "Link {$links[$k]} has a title\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
    echo "Link {$links[$k]} does not have a title\n";
}
```

### Execution

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ php test.php
Link https://amzn.to/3x4dxLF has a title
Link https://amzn.to/3qQcrQf does not have a title
Link https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2 has a title
Link https://github.com/not_found_page does not have a title
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$
```

Comment: the speed of this is amazing but it doesnt compare if the title is inside the url

Comment: What do you mean by "compare if the title is inside the url"? It frankly checks whether the response contains `<title>` or not.

Comment: yes but some pages has the title <title> Page not found </title>  and the url is like https://link.com/the-page-should-be-here . 
So what i am trying to do is to scrap the title and to check if could be found on the url, so the return can be Yes it is, or yes is not.

Comment: Simply you can just customize your validation, if you see "Page not found" on the title, then return "No". The focus here is about the performance, you should really adjust the given solution based on your own need.

Comment: sorry for stealing your time.. but i really dont understand how to get the title as variable to check it, using your solution... if you can give me a little help with this too would be apreciated.

Comment: I added the title validation against "Page not found". Could you accept the answer now?

Comment: anyway i will accept the answer, is the most helpful, Thank you alot, but still for some reason doesnt work with amz page. Check this one. https://amzn.to/3qQcrQf

Comment: You could have saved a lot of time if you mentioned that at the beginning. It didn't work with the Amazon link because that short link redirects you to another page, so you need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true for that. And then the `<title>` tag on there seems to have a newline before its close tag, so you need to change the pattern to implement `PCRE_DOTALL`, it will be `"/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/isS"`. I edited the answer.

Comment: i dont want to check only for amazon thats why. But still doesnt work properly. Thank you also for explaination, not only for the code.

https://amzn.to/3x4dxLF - valid link
https://amzn.to/3qQcrQf - invalid link

I tested and for both it said, it has no title

Comment: @TooFast it turned out that Amazon detected the automation, when I dumped the response from the curl, it showed this message: `Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.`

Comment: It show different page with different `<title>` pattern, something with attribute inside them `<title attr="blabla">`. I don't know what to do with this, but probably a cookie could trick them.

Comment: the small code i posted, it works for me but the time is too long.

Comment: @TooFast I tried to replicate the browser request by adding some HTTP headers. It works from my end now. Hope this workaround really does the job for you. I edited the answer.

Comment: Also handle the cookie, they really want you to handle the cookie.

Comment: looks like it works with some few links, i wonder what happens if i put all my 10k links :))) What do u think ? btw Thank you alot for all ur time, i will mark ur answer.

Comment: I think the Amazon may block your IP and still detect you as a robot. That's frankly a denial thing to do. You need a delay for that. If you want to gather the data as much as possible, do it in parallel and distribute your traffic across multiple proxies, so their firewall won't block you.

Comment: Curl supports many options including proxy, you should really want to learn about curl library for that.

Comment: i/c.. the script doesnt work at all anymore. I assume for amz its more complicate than other websites. If i run it on localhost it works, if i host it on a godaddy server, it doesnt work anymore.. spend a whole day for this.. Thank  you again for all ur effort